# Fill an input field from an "external" lists

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an html form.
In one input field I have to insert the Customer.

I have a mysql database with all the customers (maybe 1000 or more).
As there are a lot of results, I don't want to use a dropdown list or something like that.

I want to put near the input field a button, and when I click on it it creates a popup with a list of all customer and some customizable filters, so i can search and double click on the desired customer and it puts the customer name (with ID in the Value) in the input form.

I don't find an example to do something like that, but I know that a lot of websites uses this kind of thing.

Can you help me to find an example or can you give me some hint on how to proceed?

Used languages: HTML, PHP, mysql, jquery, javascript

Thank you

Comment: you can refer  `bootstrap modal` and in that modal you can populate your data and on selecting name you can take that name by javascript id and put that name in input field with javascript

remember bootstap modal is your popop

Comment: i recommended bootstrap because it is responsive

Answer (score 0):

On button click, Call a PHP file using ajax to load all the customers into a popup-box. Call `dblclick()` jquery fucntion to add the `value`, `id` of the customer into the input field.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="inputField" name="CustomerName" />
<input type="text" class="inputField2" name="CustomerId" />
```

**POPUP HTML**

```
<ul>
<li><span data-cust-value="Cutomer some" data-cust-id="2" >Cutomer some</a></li>
<li><span data-cust-value="Cutomer some one" data-cust-id="3" >Cutomer some one</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JQuery**

```
$( ".customerValues" ).dblclick(function() {
    $('.inputField').val($(this).attr('data-cust-value'));
    $('.inputField2').val($(this).attr('data-cust-id'));
});
```